# Mock returns Wrong Collection

Tags: java, junit, collections, mockito

I want to return a filled Map with my mocked Object, but the size of the Map is always Null. The mocked Object "CommandLineValues options" is not Null and also the Boolean variable "doCleanFirst" I can mock successfully.

Here is my Testclass:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class IndexBMECatTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private IndexBMECat classUnderTest;

    @Mock
    private CommandLineValues options;

    @Test
    public void testAccessoryItemHasNoDublicates() {

        Map<String, String> testMap = new HashMap<>();
        testMap.put("key", "value");

        when(options.getCleanFirst()).thenReturn(false);
        when(options.readWhitlist()).thenReturn(testMap);
        
        classUnderTest.run();
    }
}
```

Here is the constructor of my class where the code start, the tested Method is not relevant:

```
private boolean doCleanFirst;
private Map<String, String> whiteList;

public IndexBMECat(TransportClient client, CommandLineValues options, BMECatReader reader) throws Exception {
             
        this.doCleanFirst = options.getCleanFirst();
        this.whiteList = options.readWhitlist();
      
        if (whiteList.isEmpty()) {
            throw new Exception("Missing whiteList");
        }
    }
```

I also tried other variants:

1. Mock the Map and the return value of the method "isEmpty"
2. Initialize the Testclass and give the mocked Object to the constructor

But the whiteList has always the size = 0

[image]

Comment: The instance of IndexBMECat is created before your test is executed, so when constructor executes your mocks have not been set up. You are not mocking doCleanFirstSuccessfully -- false is just the default return value.

Comment: so should it work when I do what I write at point 2:Initialize the Testclass and give the mocked Object to the constructor ?

Comment: I don't know, you'll need to add the code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thx, this works now:

```
private IndexBMECat classUnderTest;

    @Mock
    private CommandLineValues options;

    @Mock
    private BMECatReader reader;

    @Mock
    TransportClient client;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> testMap = new HashMap<>();
        testMap.put("key", "value");
        when(options.getCleanFirst()).thenReturn(false);
        when(options.readWhitlist()).thenReturn(testMap);
        classUnderTest = new IndexBMECat(client, options, reader);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAccessoryItemHasNoDublicates() {

        classUnderTest.run();
    }
```

First I mock the methods which will be executed in the contructor and then I create the instance of my testclass.